# Plotly: How to prepare data visualization for below image using scatter bubble chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-science

Here is my dataset after cleaning csv file

[image]

Here is output what I want

[image]

What I want is , I have to display years in x axis and column values in y axis.and I want to display bubbles with different colors and size with play animation button

I am new to data science , can someone help me ,how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask).
You should avoid to add code as picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your dataset and attached image, what you're *asking* for is something like this:

[image]

But I'm not sure that is what you actually *want*. You see, with your particular dataset there aren't enough dimensions to justify an animation. Or even a bubble plot. This is because you're only looking at *one* value. So you end up showing the same value throuh the bubble sizes and on the y axis. And there's really no need to change your dataset given that your provided screenshot is in fact your desired plot. But we can talk more about that if you'd like.

Since you haven't provided a sample dataset, I've used a dataset that's available through plotly express and reshaped it so that is matches your dataset:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

# color cycle
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet*10

# sample data with similar structure as OP
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Americas'")
dfp=df.pivot(index='year', columns='country', values='pop')
dfp=dfp[['United States', 'Mexico', 'Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Colombia']]
dfp=dfp.sort_values(by='United States', ascending = False)
dfp=dfp.T
dfp.columns = [str(yr) for yr in dfp.columns]
dfp = dfp[dfp.columns[::-1]].T

# build figure and add traces
fig=go.Figure()
for col, country in enumerate(dfp):
    vals = dfp[country].values
    yVals = [col]*len(vals)
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(

        y=yVals,
        x=dfp.index,
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color=colors[col],
            size=vals,
            sizemode='area',
            #sizeref=2.*max(vals)/(40.**2),
            sizeref=2.*max(dfp.max())/(40.**2),
            sizemin=4),
        name = country
    ))

# edit y tick layout
tickVals = np.arange(0, len(df.columns))
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = tickVals,
                 ticktext = dfp.columns.tolist()))


fig.show()
```